# logic to create more rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, union, unpivot, lateral-join

I have a table1 that I wanted to transform into the expected table.

- Expected table logic for columns:
- cal: comes from cal of table1. ID comes from the ID of table1.
- code: this is populated with lp or fp depending upon if we have a value in f_a then we create a new record with fp as code. corresponding to it we check if f_a is populated if yes then we take that date from f_a and put in in the Al column for the same ID. also we check if f_pl is populated if yes then we take the date from that and put it in the pl column.
- If the code was lp then we check if l_a is populated then we take that date and place in the date in Al for that code and Id. also, we check if lpl is populated if yes then we take that date and put it in pl.

I am just a starter with SQL so it is a bit overwhelming for me on how to get it started. Please post some solutions.

table1:

```
ID  f_a            l_a           f_pl       lpl               cal
CNT 6/20/2018      6/28/2018                6/28/2018         1/31/2020
```

expected output:

```
ID  Cal             code          pl            Al 
CNT 1/31/2020       lp        6/28/2018   6/28/2018 
CNT 1/31/2020       fp                    6/20/2018
```

Update:
I have more IDs in the table, so it is not that CNT is the only Id. If I use unpivot then it should follow the same logic for all IDs.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Just a note, tables have _rows_, not records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this script which is not version dependend:

```
-- Here we select columns foom source table. Please change the names if they are different
with r as (
  select
    ID,
    f_a,
    l_a,
    f_pl,
    lpl, -- Here not sure if example is wrong or no underscore in column deffinition
    cal
  from table_1 --  Please put real table name here
)
select * from (
select r.id, r.cal, 'lp' as code, r.l_pl as pl, l_a as ai
from r
where r.l_a is not null
union all
select r1.id, r1.cal, 'pl', r1.f_pl, r1.f_a 
from r r1
where r1.f_a is not null
)
order by id, cal, code;
```

Comment: I made some changes to your code and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KSp - Thanks, my fault. Forgot alias. Script is updasted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about how to *unpivot* columns to rows. In Oracle, I would recommend a lateral join:

```
select t.id, t.cal, x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select 'lp' as code, t.lpl as pl, l_a as al from dual
    union all
    select 'fp', t.f_pl, t.f_a from dual
) x
```

This syntax is available in Oracle 12.1 onwards. In earlier versions, you would use `union all`:

```
select id, cal, 'lp' as code, lpl as pl, l_a as al from mytable
union all
select id, cal, 'lp' as code, 'fp', f_pl, f_a from mytable
```

Comment: Why not just unpivot on (f_a, f_pl) as 'fp', (l_a, l_pl) as 'lp'? Is lateral faster/less resource-consuming? As of readability, I think lateral join requires more effort to read and extract real value from code

Comment: @GMB the result does split into two records and code column as lp two times on the same value instead of fp, fp is shown in a new field.

Comment: see the updated output so you can see what I am getting from your query.

Comment: @KSp It is strange because I've used this code in my fiddle (replace mytable to a in it) and got the same output as UNPIVOD did. Moreover you cannot get those results since there's no field named "field1" in his script.

Comment: @KSp: the query I provided you with cannot possibly generate the output that you are showing. Here is a db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad350ebdb5eeed04d9db6d11e35ffe79. You can see that this is the output that you expect.

Comment: I am getting an error as t.f_pl  field not found although I see it in my table. Also, instead of cross apply or unpivot both do not work for me. So I am using join.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for multiple columns then do the checks you need on dates:

```
with a as (
  select
    'CNT' as ID,
    date '2018-06-20' as f_a,
    date '2018-06-28' as l_a,
    cast(null as date) as f_pl,
    date '2018-06-28' as l_pl,
    date '2020-01-31' as cal
  from dual
)
select *
from a
unpivot(
  (pl, al) for code in ((l_pl, l_a) as 'lp', (f_pl, f_a) as 'fp')
) up
```

```
ID  | CAL       | CODE | PL        | AL
CNT | 31-JAN-07 | lp   | 28-JUN-18 | 28-JUN-18
CNT | 31-JAN-07 | fp   |           | 20-JUN-18
```

[Working example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f58fa3db36e9205541a8e883ef3634f0).

Comment: pls note that i am not trying to get values only for one date set, I have to apply for whole table.

Comment: @KSp What did you mean? Unpivot does know nothing about datasets and tables, it just unpivot columns to rows. Need clarification of your statement

Comment: Are you saying that if i have more rows with different id in my table, it follows the same logic?

Comment: @KSp It's better to feed more data in example and test it by yourself, but yes, it will do the same because unpivot keeps other fields unchanged. Just gets field (or group of fields), transforms it's name to value as declared in IN part of UNPIVOT, and put values of that column(s) to value of corresponding column(s), that declared before FOR part of UNPIVOT. And for each column group (that are in brackets after IN) it generates new row. Better to read the doc or examples: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot